# How do I remove a default command keyword?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I would like to create an `install` alias for `sudo apt-get install` but the `install` keyword is already taken. Can I remove this keyword and how do I do it?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do so without hiding the default `install` command because aliases take precedence over commands. I recommend choosing another word as the alias. You can use `get` for example.

Comment: technically, aliases take precedence over  commands, therefore it's not recommended to use same name for alias. Personally, I'd just prefix aliases with a_ , like a_install. that way there's no confusion that it's an alias

Comment: @Serg Thanks. Added the precedence word in the answer :)